# ember-cli-eslint, ember-cli-stylelint to run automatically only if desired

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I understand that the purpose of `ember-cli-eslint`, `ember-cli-stylelint` to run automatically.

I am wondering if there is a way to control this behavior.

Like, run `ember-cli-eslint`, `ember-cli-stylelint` automatically only if there is certain `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` or maybe write a custom script.

I am wondering if that is possible. Google search did not provide me any pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@Turbo87](https://github.com/Turbo87) at https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-eslint/issues/333 I have updated `ember-cli-build.js` like so:

```js
const blacklist = [];
if (process.env.DISABLE_AUTO_LINT) {
  blacklist.push('ember-cli-eslint', 'ember-cli-eslint');
}

let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  addons: { blacklist },
});
```

And it works as desired.

A simplified `package.json/script` looks something like so:

```js
"scripts": {
  "eslint": "eslint .",
  "stylelint": "stylelint app/styles",
  "lint": "npm run eslint && npm run stylelint",
  "start": "DISABLE_AUTO_LINT=true ember serve",
  "test": "npm run lint --silent && DISABLE_AUTO_LINT=true ember exam --split=10 --parallel",
}
```

`ember serve` functions as business as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For ESLint:

1. Remove the addon ember-cli-eslint
2. Install the npm package eslint in your project

ESLint will then run only when you actually run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint .`

You should update your package.json's `lint:js` script as well.

For Stylelint:

1. Remove the addon ember-cli-stylelint
2. Install the npm package stylelint in your project

Stylelint will then run only when you actually run `./node_modules/.bin/stylelint`

You should update your package.json's `lint:css` script as well.

Comment: I am using the binaries but didn't want to remove the `ember-cli-eslint` and `ember-cli-styelint` as few folks in my projects like them more and have their dev workflow based on it. I didn't want to introduce a disruptive change.